# RegEx matching help: won't match on each appearence

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to write a little RegEx matcher which will match any occurrence of strings in the form of

`[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?`

If I use the regex above it does match the sections needed but would also match onto the `abc` part of `4_abc` which is not intended. I tried to exclude it with:

`(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9_]|^)([a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9_]|$)`

The problem is that the 'not' matches at the beginning and end are not really working like I hoped they would. If I use them on the example

`a_d Dd_da 4_d d_4`

they would block matching the second Dd_da because the space was used in the first match.Sadly I can't use lookarounds because I am using JS.

So the input:
`a_d Dd_da 4_d d_4`

should match: `a_d`, `Dd_da` and `d_4`

but matches:  `a_d` (there is a space at the end)

Is there another way to match the needed sections, or to not consume the 'anchor' matches?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What about `\b`? [`\b[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/XS4C23/1)

Comment: @trincot that worked!! I ignored that before because I though `∧` `∨` might be counted as "part of the word" but that solved the issue! Can you please repost this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `\b`:

[`\b[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/XS4C23/1/)

`\b` matches the (zero-width) point where either the preceding character or following character is a letter, digit or underscore, but not both. It also matches with the start/end of the string if the first/last character is a letter, digit or underscore.